# Регулярное выражение проверки имени

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Необходимо написать регулярное выражение для проверки фамилии, чтобы:

1. Либо кириллица или латинница.
2. Допускались символы в ней ' и -
3. Не больше 50 символов

Пробовал пробовал:

```
^((([A-Z]?)[a-z]+|)|(([А-Я]?)[а-я]+))$
^([A-ZА-Я][a-zа-я]('[a-zа-я]|-[а-яa-z]){1,19})?$
```

не подходят.

Comment: под такой валидатор не попадут почти все иностранные фамилии, особенно французские и немецкие. и даже испанские - у них бывают пробелы в фамилиях. валидатор на фамилию - достаточно бесполезная вещь.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/146901/

Answer (score 3):

Если JavaScript, это должно заработать:

```
/^([A-Za-z\-\']{1,50})|([А-Яа-я\-\']{1,50})$/
```

Если также необходимо чтобы первая буква была прописной, а остальные строчными:

```
/^([A-Z][a-z\-\']{1,50})|([А-Я][а-я\-\']{1,50})$/
```

**UPD:**

Для поддержки букв не попадающих в диапазон а-я, думаю, придется писать список вручную.

Если первая буква должна быть заглавной:

```
/^([A-Z][a-z\-\']{1,50})|([А-ЯЁIЇҐЄ][а-яёіїґє\-\']{1,50})$/
```

Если регистр не имеет значения:

```
/^([A-Za-z][A-Za-z\-\']{1,50})|([А-ЯЁIЇҐЄа-яёіїґє][А-ЯЁIЇҐЄа-яёіїґє\-\']{1,50})$/
```

Список символов не полный тут только ё для русского и іїґє для украинского.

**UPD2:**

Полный список кириллических символов исключая исторические и не славянские (согласно Википедии [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кириллица](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)):

```
/^([A-Z][a-z\-\']{1,50})|([А-ЯЁIЇҐЄЂЃЀЅЍЈЉЊЋЌЎ][а-яёіїґєђѓѐѕѝјљњћќў\-\']{1,50})$/
```

Comment: А-Я - это не все символы киррилицы. `ё`, например, вне этого диапазона

Comment: и как быть ? добавть Ёё ?

Comment: нет, ваш не продходит, фамилия не может начинаться с - или апострофа, логично ж

Comment: @pirogi ё. и другие символы. Зно**ў** запамятавал**і** пра нас, беларуса**ў**? Я уже не говорю про казахов - у них вроде тоже киррилица.

Comment: @pirogi у вас в вопросе ничего нет про то, что фамилия не может начинаться с апострофа

Comment: Все равно к сож его не подходит регулярка

Comment: Нет, вы правы, но думаю это и понятно само по себе что она не модет начинаться с символов

Comment: Українська кирилиця на жаль також потребує окремого піклування.

Comment: @omegascorp оч хорошо, но так он пропускает заглавных сколько угодно первых(

Comment: @pirogi: А с заглавными вообще засада. Что делать с фамилией Сквозник-Дмухановский? д'Артаньян? ван Бастен?

Answer (score 3):

Крайне не рекомендую проверять имена регулярками: http://habrahabr.ru/post/146901/

Помимо всевозможных Гюльчитай Ахмад оглы Сулеймамбековых возможны имена натурализовавшихся китайцев, португальцев (с тремя-пятью «отчествами», которые на самом деле — вторые и т.п. имена) и так далее

То есть как студенческое поделие — можно. Как промышленный код — ни в коем разе!

Answer (score 1):

Для Юникода (любые языки)

```
/^[\p{L}\p{M}][\p{L}\p{M}\'\-]{0,48}[\p{L}\p{M}]$/u
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/gM6pE0/1

`\p{L}` - все буквенные символы.

`\p{M}` - все диакритические знаки.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[а-яёa-z][-а-яёa-z']{0,49}$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Давайте по порядку:

- Либо кириллица (русские буквы) или латинница: `^([a-zA-Z]+|[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)$`
- Допускались символы в ней `'` и `-`: `^([a-zA-Z'-]+|[а-яА-ЯёЁ'-]+)$`
- Не больше 50 символов (от 0 до 50): `^([a-zA-Z'-]{0,50}|[а-яА-ЯёЁ'-]{0,50})$`.

*Подробности*:

- `^` - начало строки
- `(`  - начало захватывающей подмаски:

  - `[a-zA-Z'-]{0,50}` - от нуля до пятидесяти символов `'`, `-` или латинских букв
- `|` - или

  - `[а-яА-ЯёЁ'-]{0,50}` - от нуля до пятидесяти символов `'`, `-` или русских букв
- `)` - конец захватывающей подмаски:
- `$` - конец строки.

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/oxyCoI/1).

```js
const names = ["O'James-Jensen", "Смит", "Goldсмит"];
const ubound = 50;
const regex = new RegExp(`^([a-zA-Z'-]{0,50}|[а-яА-ЯёЁ'-]{0,${ubound}})$`);
// => /^([a-zA-Z'-]{0,50}|[а-яА-ЯёЁ'-]{0,50})$/
for (const name of names) {
    console.log(name, '=>', regex.test(name));
}
```

Если нужна поддержка *любых* кириллических букв, используйте

```
/^([a-zA-Z'-]{0,50}|[\p{scx=Cyrl}'-]{0,50})$/u
```

Если нужна полная поддержка Юникода и неважно, смешаны ли кириллические буквы с латинскими или нет, используйте

```
/^[\p{L}\p{M}'-]{0,50}$/u
```