# RegEx для ввода имени и фамили, а также двойной фамили через -

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, .net

Нужна проверка введенной в форму имени и фамилии, а также двойной фамилии, например Irina Naro-fominskaja

Comment: Вопрос поставлен не в правильной форме. Опишите в вопросе то, что именно вы хотели бы проверять и тд. Т.е. опишите правила проверки.

Comment: видимо где то так `\w+\s\w+(-\w+)?`. Я специально не ограничивал длину имени и фамилии, так как мне известен человек с именем "Ия Эм".

Comment: Имелось ввиду проверка наличия двух слов (Имя Фамилия, а также двойная фамилия), латинские буквы, независимо от регистра.

Comment: KoVadim, спасибо, работает.

Comment: Вопрос похож на http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448934/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8 Правда там тоже послали на хабр :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @KoVadim: был знакомый с фамилией «Ю», китаец.

Answer (score 4):

**Валидация имён и фамилий — это плохая идея**. Вы ничего этим не добьётесь, кроме раздражения пользователей, когда им понадобится ввести что-то, что не проходит проверку вашей "универсальной регуляркой".

Обратимся к классике:

> Итак, ради всеобщего блага, я составил список предположений, которые ваша система, вероятно, может делать об именах людей. **Все эти предположения ошибочны**. Попробуйте хотя бы уменьшить список, когда будете проектировать систему в следующий раз.
>
> 1. У каждого человека есть одно каноническое полное имя.
> 2. У каждого человека есть одно полное имя, которое он использует.
> 3. В данный момент времени у каждого человека есть одно каноническое полное имя.
> 4. В данный момент времени у каждого человека есть одно полное имя, которое он использует.
> 5. У каждого человека есть в точности N имён, независимо от значения N.
> 6. Имена вмещаются в определённое количество символов.
> 7. Имена не меняются.
> 8. Имена меняются, но только в определённых ограниченных случаях.
> 9. Имена записаны в ASCII.
> 10. Имена записаны в какой-нибудь одной кодировке.
> 11. Все имена соответствуют символам Unicode.
> 12. Имена чувствительны к смене регистра.
> 13. Имена не чувствительны к смене регистра.
> 14. Иногда в именах встречаются префиксы или суффиксы, но вы можете безопасно их игнорировать.
> 15. Имена не содержат цифр.
> 16. Имена не могут быть записаны ЦЕЛИКОМ ПРОПИСНЫМИ буквами.
> 17. Имена не могут быть записаны целиком строчными буквами.
> 18. В именах есть порядок. Выбор одной их схем упорядочивания записи автоматически приведёт к постоянному порядку среди всех систем, если все они используют ту же схему упорядочивания.
> 19. Имя и фамилия обязательно отличаются.
> 20. У людей есть фамилия или что-то подобное, общее для родственников.
> 21. Имя человека уникально.
> 22. Имя человека почти уникально.
> 23. Ладно, ладно, но имена достаточно редки, так что нет миллиона человек с тем же именем и фамилией.
> 24. Моя система никогда не будет иметь дело с именами из Китая.
> 25. Или Японии.
> 26. Или Кореи.
> 27. Или Ирландии, Великобритании, США, Испании, Мексики, Бразилии, Перу, Швеции, Ботсваны, ЮАР, Тринидада, Гаити, Франции, Клингонской Империи — во всех перечисленных используются «странные» схемы для имён.
> 28. Клингонская Империя была шуткой, правда?
> 29. К чёрту культурный релятивизм! Люди в моём обществе, по крайней мере, имеют одинаковое представление об общепризнанном стандарте для имён.
> 30. Есть алгоритм, который преобразует имена в одну и другую сторону без потерь. (Да, да, ты можешь сделать это, если алгоритм на выходе возвращает то же, что и на входе, возьми себе медаль).
> 31. Я могу уверенно предположить, что этот словарь нецензурных слов не содержит фамилий.
> 32. Имена людям даются при рождении.
> 33. OK, может не при рождении, но довольно скоро после него.
> 34. Ладно, ладно, в течение года или около того.
> 35. Пять лет?
> 36. Ты шутишь, верно?
> 37. Две различные системы, в которых указано имя одного и того же человека, будут использовать для него одно и то же имя.
> 38. Два различных оператора ввода данных, если им дать имя человека, обязательно впишут один и тот же набор символов, если система хорошо спроектирована.
> 39. Люди, чьи имена ломают мою систему, — странные чужаки. У них должны быть нормальные, приемлемые имена, вроде (последовательность иероглифов).
> 40. У людей есть имена.
>
> Список ни в коем случае не исчерпывающий. Если вам нужны примеры реальных имён, которые опровергают любой из этих пунктов, я с удовольствием назову их. Можете добавлять в комментариях другие пункты для этого списка заблуждений, и отправляйте людям ссылку на этот список в следующий раз, когда им придёт в голову гениальная идея сделать базу данных с колонками first_name и last_name.

Соус: http://habrahabr.ru/post/146901/

Comment: Оригинал: Patrick McKenzie, [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)